# Serverless Node TypeScript app can't import module

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm tired of this error! This is Serverless app with Lambda in AWS. Locally it works perfectly. Testing locally didn't work for load of other reasons. I'm testing in staging. Yet I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to import module 'src/engine/handler': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous>(/var/task/src/engine/controllers/image.js:43:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I followed all the steps advised elsewhere including: moving all dependencies to dependencies (out of dev), installing serverless and all. I'm using Node 6.10.3 and TypeScript 3.1. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying host your nodejs projects which has so many dependencies not related to aws services inside, you better zip your projects in S3 first then import lambda from S3.

Comment: But the dependency it's asking for is written by me. I'm only importing the `controller/image.ts` module as shown in error. Does this still apply?

Comment: error showing is `Unable to import module 'src/engine/handler': Error`

Comment: Jeez how dumb of me! Thanks! Will try what you said.

Comment: @LeeMoe pls don't forgot to mark my answer as correct after you fixed it. :D

Comment: I did it (again because this is how it was done first place) and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Better use `require` instead `import`.

Comment: With require I end up with another kind of errors. I shouldn't have gone TypeScrip first place. Anyway, thank you!